# Share dialog app requires login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), it says that Facebook Login is not required to use the Share Dialog. I've developed an app that uses the Share Dialog, and it all works fine in testing.

However, when it comes to approving the app, under "App Details" it tells me this:

> Your submission contains the following errors:
>
> - You must choose at least one platform to be displayed

I don't actually need the app listed in FB's app center, but it seems to require it. So then I check the Android option, and instead I get this error:

> Facebook Login has not been used successfully on your app in the past
>   30 days. Please test Facebook Login with your app prior to submitting
>   for review. Be sure to test the entire login flow, starting with the
>   TOS agreement (this may require uninstalling and reinstalling your
>   app). We will remove your app from the App Center if we determine that
>   you have not integrated Facebook Login correctly.

Now naturally since the app just uses the Share Dialog, which doesn't need a login, I haven't implemented login.

How do I get past this? I've read through a LOT of docs on the FB website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the app to be listed in Facebook's app center. You need to go to Your App > Settings > Add Platform > Website and list the Site URL. Facebook apps require a "platform" to be specified (web, iPhone, canvas etc).

Comment: Yeah, this isn't very obvious from the docs. When you try to get an Open Graph action approved, it needs you to put in some stuff on the app details page. What it doesn't tell you is that it doesn't need all the details.