# Facebook share dialog requires login

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I'm trying to implement a facebook share-dialog on my site through the Facebook Javascript SDK. I'm using the 'share' method as recommended in FB docs.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

The share dialog works fine when I'm logged in as the admin of the FB app. However, when logged in with an account that doesn't have a role defined for the app, I get the following error.

> App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

I made sure that:

- The app is public
- The website platform was added to the app (cf. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407764/share-dialog-app-requires-login))

My app doesn't implement the Facebook login.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app on which I was testing was in fact a [test version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps) of my Facebook app. As clearly stated in Facebook docs, Public Mode can't be activated on test apps, and hence, share dialog can't work for other users than the users defined for the test app. Poor me ...